# Найти минимум функции многих переменных

Tags: python, теория

Нужно найти минимум функции f(x) = f(x1, x2,.. ,xn), есть два ограничения.Для этого использую scipy.optimize с методом SLSQP - метод последовательного квадратичного программирования.
Ссылка на документацию по этой функции: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Объясните пожалуйста смысл начального значения x0 = (х01, х02, .. , х0n), каким его задавать и от чего оно зависит? Из документации так и не поняла

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что это итерационный метод. т.е. новое приближение к минимуму получается из предыдущего приближения.

Соответственно нужно начальное значение x_0 для старта метода.

Выбирается оно произвольно, но должно лежать на самой функции.

Например `f(x,y)=x^2+xy+3y^2, x_0=(1,1)`

Comment: Что значит лежать на самой функции? Принадлежать области ее определения?

Comment: Да. Если есть ограничения, то в них.